# "cannot find symbol - class Scanner" error

Tags: java

This is my Code

```
public class Workshop3
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("please enter radius of circle");
        double radius;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        keyboard.nextDouble (radius);
    }
}
```

The error I recieve is

> cannot find symbol - class scanner

on the line

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
```

Answer (score 27):

As the OP is a new beginner to programming, I would like to explain more.

You wil need this line on the top of your code in order to compile:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

This kind of import statement is very important. They tell the compile of which kind of Scanner you are about to use, because the Scanner here is undefined by anyone.

After a import statement, you can use the class Scanner directly and the compiler will know about it.

Also, you can do this without using the import statement, although I don't recommend:

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

In this case, you just directly tell the compiler about which Scanner you mean to use.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the line `import java.util.Scanner;` in your source file somewhere, preferably at the top.

Answer (score 5):

You have to import java.util.Scanner at first line in the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this error by importing the `java.util.*` package - you can do this by adding following line of code to top of your program (with your other `import` statements):

```
import java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes this can occur during when we try to print string from the user so before we print we have to use

eg: 
Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);

scan.nextLine(); 
 // if we have output before this string from the user like integer or other dat type in the buffer there is /n (new line) which skip our string so we use this line to print our string

String s=scan.nextLine();

System.out.println(s);

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following line on top of your code

```
*import java.util.*;*
```

This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Add import java.util.Scanner; at the very top of your code. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i have a same problem on the line
this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num= s.nextInt(),a=0,rev=0;
    while(num>0){
        a=num%10;
        rev+=a;
        num/=10;
        if(num==0){
          break;
        }
        rev*=10;
    }
    System.out.println("reversed: "+rev);
    }
 }
```

and i got

```
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        ^
symbol:   class Scanner
location: class Main
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                      ^
symbol:   class Scanner
location: class Main
2 errors
```

i even try some varies methods to import the Scanner class, that even work well.