# Why I am getting "Cannot find symbol error " in this code?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn abstract method and abstract class but I don't understand why I am getting error. Can anyone please help me find the cause of the error?

I've tried to check the spellings of java file and class and methods. But they seem fine.

```
// Code from filename: Person.java 
// abstract class
abstract class Person {
    public String fname = "John";
    public int age = 24;
    public abstract void study(); // abstract method 
  }

  // Subclass (inherit from Person)
  class Student extends Person {
    public int graduationYear = 2018;
    public void study() { // the body of the abstract method is provided here
      System.out.println("Studying all day long");
    }
  }
// End code from filename: Person.java

// Code from filename: MyClass.java
class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an object of the Student class (which inherits attributes and methods from Person)
    Student myObj = new Student(); 

    System.out.println("Name: " + myObj.fname);
    System.out.println("Age: " + myObj.age);
    System.out.println("Graduation Year: " + myObj.graduationYear);
    myObj.study(); // call abstract method
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> MyClass.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>       Student myObj = new Student(); 
>       ^                   ^   symbol:   class Student   location: class MyClass

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959061/cannot-find-symbol-class-scanner-error

Comment: You need to ensure your class locations match their packages and also make sure you add the appropriate imports.

Comment: Does all your three classes belong to the same packages?

Comment: I think it should be `Person.Student` and not `Student`. You can alternatively do `import static Student;` Also, the Subclass `Student` should be `static`.

Comment: Stak cla. did You complile Person.java ? Do You have Person.class in Your project directory ? I reproduced Your error when i didn't compile Person.java , but just compiled MyClass.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time! I was using VS code and getting that error but when I tried Eclipse, I didn't get any error. Then I tried to install some extensions to VS code and it worked.

Comment: Ideally, move `Student` out of the `Person` class. I don't see any reason why you'd want it to be a nested class - it adds a lot of complication.

Answer (score -1):

All your classes have no-modifier access level, which means they are visible only to the package. Put `MyClass` in the same package as `Person` / `Student` or change them to be `public class...`.

See this for detailed explanation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_modifier_types.htm